# I am getting a error when i press the back button of the browser(ASP.NET PAGE)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

I am developing a ASP.NET application..i have developed three pages in my application..after saving to database ,if i press the back button in browser i am getting [image]

How to avoid this error in ASP.NET???

Comment: The previous page was doing a POST.  Employing the [PRG Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) will eliminate the error.

Comment: This is happening because of postbacks that happen in asp.net webforms as part of the page lifecycle.

Comment: See answers for [How do I implement the Post/Redirect/Get pattern in asp.net WebForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919516/how-do-i-implement-the-post-redirect-get-pattern-in-asp-net-webforms).

Comment: This is normal, don't fight it but plan around it. Above all do not try to change functionality of back button. On E-Commerce checkout pages I always put a notice in red font warning users not to hit the back button. Pizza Hut does this also.